# Masked Text Box removes preceeding zeros in date

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have a process which grabs the birthdate and from a data table and display them in a masked text box for viewing and editing

However when pushing the data into the textbox any preceding zeros get removed

For example 05/05/2005 would display as 55/20/05__

The masked Text box is set up as 00/00/0000

The line which assigns the code is:

```
MaskedTextBox.Text = Format(DataTable(0)("DOB"), “MM/dd/yyyy”).ToString
```

To date I have tried the following:

- Delete and re-add the control
- Copy masked textbox from another form
  in the same program
- Above Masked textbox grabs the same
  information from the same database
  table and is formatted exactly the
  same and it works
- Tried various different formats
  including no format all with the same
  result

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: What is the string that comes out of the call to `Format`

Comment: +1 And does the .ToString affect that result?  I'd guess it's not an issue with the control, but with the right hand side of the code

Comment: tried it without .tostring same result
also I have the same control on nother form pulling exactly the same data and formatted exactly the same. However it works on that form not on this form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to replicate the problem but currently there doesn't seem to be a solution.  What you need is a binding navigator toolbar on the top of your form with your data bound masked text box with any mask (doesn't matter which one).  When you run the form, initially the masked text box will accept the data just fine.  However, if you click the "AddNewItem" button (the plus sign button) on your binding navigator toolbar, it will cause the masked text box to delete all preceding zeros when you try to enter a date. It seems all masks will do this.  Rebuilding the form won't fix it, either.  It happens every time you hit the "AddNewItem" button and then proceed to enter data into any formatted masked text box.

Now that I've found out exactly how to replicate the problem, hopefully someone more knowledgeable can come along to figure out how to circumvent this.  It seems like it is a glitch within VB.  Don't know if this constitutes as an actual "answer" but I have provided a clear path to finding a solution.  I just don't have the know-how to get that far.

(Update: I discovered that it does this to all masks, not just "short date" masks)

Comment: I went ahead and posted this as a question of my own.  I came here by trying to search google for my problem and this was the closest I could find.  Seemed more efficient to post my own question about the problem and provide the way to replicate the issue.  I will update this once I get an answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am going to have to put this in "Mysteries of the Unexplained " box.

At the advice of another developer I manually recreated the form, re-added all the controls and it now works fine (copy and pasting all the controls from one form to another caused the issue to come with it).

I really don't know how to even recreate the issue must be something in the forms design level code???

Anyway thanks for all the assistance from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the Datatable data to date and back:

```
MaskedTextBox.Text = Date.Parse(DataTable(0)("DOB")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

My guess is that either the database is sending the date in a format you don't expect, you changed the control's Culture (under Behaivior properties), or that you changed the way your computer shows dates and thus changed its culture. However I try I can't replicate the problem with my culture settings.

Comment: Got this 84/19/69_1 as a result

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Masked a Text Box control that was added at runtime. I was just trying to add the date of the day to the control

Visual studio 2013

```
Dim Today As Date = Now.Date
tbox_ShipDate.Text = FormatDateTime(Today,DateFormat.ShortDate) 'Failed every time
```

Problem was solved by using

```
tbox_ShipDate.Text = Format(Today, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

seemed to simple but all worked well

Comment: Sorry, I no longer work at the same company where that issue arose, also I was using VS 2008 .net3.5 (I think) at the time.